# MVC Areas in a Webforms project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a VERY large website that has classic asp and webforms.  I have successfully added MVC and it is working great but...  the number of controllers/views is going to massive and I need to organize them.

I would like to use Areas but I cannot find any examples of it working.

I have placed my "Controllers" folder in the "App_Code" folder (if there is a better way, please tell me) and would like my structure to have 2 more levels like this:

```
App_Code/Controllers/Level1/LeveA/FooController
App_Code/Controllers/Level1/LeveA/BarController
App_Code/Controllers/Level1/LeveB/ThisController
App_Code/Controllers/Level1/LeveB/ThatController
```

and want the views the same way:

```
Views/Level1/LeveA/Foo/Index.cshtml
Views/Level1/LeveA/Foo/UpdateFoo.cshtml
```

Anyone have any idea how to set this up?????

*** This is a web site not a web application, that is why I put the controller in the App_Code

Comment: No, don't put your Controllers folder in App_Code.  That's silly.  Leave all folders in their default locations unless you have a very good reason to move them.  MVC works off convention and it expects things to be in certain locations.  Don't be tempted to move your CSS or JavaScript either, since Nuget packages tend to use standardized places for these, and it makes upgrading difficult.

Comment: If you know a better to get MVC to work in a web site project, I am open to it

Comment: I deleted my answer since it didn't pertain to the question once you clarified the project type.

Comment: @PatrickWensel - You can't use Website projects with MVC.  Your best bet would be to create a sub-application under your website to host your MVC site as it's own IIS application.

Comment: You can do it, been doing it for a few years now on other systems.  This question is about subfolders in views and controllers without using Areas